# Add custom Twig extension

Tags: services, 9

I need to output a JSON variable in my theme, data is saved in a node field. I can easily use hook_preprocess_node to decode the data and save it in axillary variable and then render it using a custom template file, but it would be much easier if I can decode JSON in twig file so there wont be need for implementing hook_preprocess_node or introducing new template file (as it can be achieved overriding `field--FIELD-NAME.html.twig`)

so I wrote a module to extend twig extension and add a `json_decode` filter to twig. this is my services.yml file:

```
services:
  twig_json_decode.twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\twig_json_decode\JsonToArray
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

and this is the JsonToArray.php :

```
namespace Drupal\twig_json_decode;


use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class JsonToArray extends AbstractExtension {

  public function getFilters(): array {
    return [
      new TwigFilter('decode_json', [$this, 'jsonDecode']),
    ];
  }

  // The actual implementation of the filter.
  public function jsonDecode($context) {
    $context = json_decode($context, true);
    if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE)
      return $context;
    return [];
  }
}
```

Then in my twig file I have:

```
{% for item in items | decode_json %}
  <div class="reqinfoitem">
    <span class="reqlableinfo">{{ item.label }} : </span>
    <span class="reqinputinfo">{{ item.answer }}</span>
  </div><!--end reqinfoitem-->
{% endfor %}
```

which cause this error:

> Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "decode_json" filter. in Twig\ExpressionParser->getFilterNodeClass()

I have the module enabled and cleared the cache but it seems that the custom filter is not affecting twig.
How can I make sure that my module is called and working properly?

--UPDATE--

I Used `drush devel:services` to get a list of available services but the service name `twig_extendion` was not listed there so it seems that my service is not introduced to Drupal, but I cant figure it out why this might happen !!!

any problem in my services.yml file?

Comment: silly me, after spending hours and hours debugging, I finally realized that I had misspelling in name of my services.yml file , I had named it as : tiwg_json_decode.services.yml where it should be twig_json_decode.services.yml :((